# Is it possible to detect java class type using El with JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

code is like this:

```
 <c:forEach  items="${itemList}" var="item">
 //do stuff based on the class type of item                                 
 </c:forEach>
```

Is it possible to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, `${item.class}` conforms to the javabeans convention, so you get the `Class`. Then you can get other properties.

If it doesn't work, use `${item['class']}`

Comment: According to https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50120 class is a reserved word in jsp, too. So you have to use ${item['class']}